# How to create an email notification (incl email/password) for new members registered via CartThrob checkout process?

Tags: members, cartthrob, notification

I have been building a new e-commerce site using CartThrob2, which is a great add-on I have to say.

However, one last issue is leaving me a little frustrated. I need to be able to automatically send out an email notification to newly registered members (which includes their email and password for logging in) once they have been through the checkout process and CartThrob adds them to the members section.

It's all working fine otherwise, but there isn't an event for new member registration or similar in the notifications settings of CartThrob.

I have read about and tried to use MX Notify Control, but that doesn't seem to work with CartThrob very well as no email comes through to the new member.

I have also read about Postmaster add-on, but after trying MX Notify Control and having no success I'm a little skeptical about paying for it unless I know for sure it will work. Plus it seems a bit overkill for what I need here.

Does anyone know of another way to do it?

Maybe creating a custom email notification withing the Design > Message Pages section on the CP?

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: strange, I've used MX Notify Control with CartThrob before to do just that. Do other email notifications work? I would always advise against ever sending a password in an email.

Comment: Hi Steven, ok that's strange. Unfortunately the client is adamant they want to send the password. I haven't tried any other notifications within MX Notify if that's what you mean. All notifications sent via CartThrob are coming through fine. Did you use the 'Member Register' trigger in MX Notify with the email set to {mbr_email}? Thanks.

Comment: you have a responsibility to tell the client no in this situation. Unless they want to become a hashtag (and not the good kind). What I meant about other notifications is whether you can send email from the communication module under tools? It may be that email sending isn't properly configured? I now run all client email delivery through Mandrill now as well because the reliability of delivery is much better. In our MX Notify case we used the email address collected by Carthrob which was {purchased_email_address}

Comment: I agree on the password, but telling the client is one thing, them listening is another! Yes the communication section works fine, as does MX Notify when using the 'CP Register' trigger. So I know the email template and tags are all ok as the email /password displayed fine. But when using the 'Member Register' (I assume that's the correct one to use?) trigger no email comes through automatically after the checkout process. I can see that the member has been created and assigned to the correct group and the order goes through ok. It's very strange and frustrating!

Comment: what about triggering the email where the order is placed and their order count is == 1 ?

Comment: Ok sounds worth a try. How do I set that up? Sorry haven't done something like that in EE before. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: not sure that will work actually as it would spit out an email to the user regardless of their order count.

Comment: Ok thanks Steven, I have tried a few things but without success. Still waiting for a reply from CartThrob support which has been quite slow unfortunately! Any other ideas anyone please?